# How to limit the value of parameter when sending a post request?

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

I have a class Comment with fields: score, author,Id,pub_date
Here is my code in serializers

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True,slug_field='username')
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','text','author','score', 'pub_date')
        model = Comment
```

Views:

```
class CommentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [MyPermissionClass]
    pagination_class = MyLimitOffsetPagination
    def get_queryset(self):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        return post.comment_set
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        a=serializer(author=self.request.user, post=post)
   if a.score<50: 
       a.save()
   else: 
       Response({'number':'must be less than 50'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But it does not work, it not only does not limit the value of the score to 50, but also breaks the whole code

Comment: Is that the actual code you're running - including the indentation? What you've posted there isn't valid Python. Your `if` statement is part of the `class` definition, not `perform_create`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is max value validation of the integer field of DRF [Link to docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#integerfield)

Try

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True,slug_field='username')
    
    score = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=50, min_value=0)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','text','author','score', 'pub_date')
        model = Comment
```

Or since your are already using model Serializer, you can provide these as extra kwargs of the field,

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True,slug_field='username')
    

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','text','author','score', 'pub_date')
        model = Comment
        extra_kwargs = {
          "score": {"min_value": 0, "max_value": 50}
        }
```

Note I have added the min value as 0.

Now you can simply your view as

```
# importing Response 
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CommentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [MyPermissionClass]
    pagination_class = MyLimitOffsetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        return post.comment_set
  
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        a=serializer(author=self.request.user, post=post)

        # raise any validation error if any
        a.is_valid(raise_expection=True)    
        a.save()
        return Response(a)
```